# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++

I have looked at other threads but none seemed to help me. I am getting this error message:

> Corpus.cpp: At global scope:
>   Corpus.cpp:12:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Here is Corpus.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Corpus.h"
#include <fstream>

double prop[26];

Corpus::Corpus() : prop {0.09, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.12, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.09, 001, 0.01, 0.04,
            0.02, 0.06, 0.08, 0.02, 0.01, 0.06, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01}
{
}

Corpus::Corpus(fstream f) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    int i=0;
    while(scan.hasNext() && i<26) {
            prop[i++] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}

char Corpus::proportion(char c) {
    int i = c=97;
    return prop[i];
}
```

And this is Corpus.h

```
#ifndef CORPUS_H
#define CORPUS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
class Corpus {
public:
    double prop[26];
    Corpus();
    Corpus(std::fstream f);
    char proportion(char c);
};

#endif
```

Comment: make a comment on the code where the error is (we have the line number in the error, but we don't have line numbers in code here :p). Use [edit] to edit the question. Otherwise good effort to post all the information in the question and format it properly. Kudos

Comment: It is called `std::fstream`. You need to use the right name in your constructor definition.

Comment: Care! you have a `001` in the init of `prop`. That is octal 1. Maybe you meant `0.01`.

Comment: You have out-of-bounds error here: `char Corpus::proportion(char c) {
    int i = c=97;
    return prop[i];
}`

Comment: The global variable `double prop[26];` is dangerous as it would be easy to mix up accesses to that variable with accesses to your class member `prop` . suggest either renaming it, or getting rid of it if you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

The first error, the one that causes that error message, is that

```
Corpus::Corpus(fstream f) {
```

should be:

```
Corpus::Corpus(std::fstream f) {
```

In the error message it said `Corpus.cpp:12:15:`  ; the `12` is the line number and `15` is the character number within that line ; so that points right to the `f` in `fstream` which is exactly where the problem was.

However, once that is fixed then more mistakes show up. `Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);` is a mistake. `Scanner` isn't defined anywhere, but even if it was, this is not Java. The C++ way to create an object would be `Scanner scan{f};`.